# I am not able to get Precise Throughput Timer working

Tags: jmeter

I don't know if I have placed the timer at the correct location. I am not able to get Precise Throughput Timer working.

[image: My Test Plan]

[image: Precise Throughput Timer]

Answer (score 0):

1. Any JMeter component needs to be placed according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules)
2. How do you expect the timer to "work" given you have only one thread and one iteration in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) especially given your test finishes in 500 **milliseconds** and you configured the test duration as 500 **seconds**

If you want to limit your test throughput to 1 request per second for 1 thread and 1 iteration only - I can only think of introducing [pacing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-easily-implement-pacing-jmeter) as none of the existing timers won't be able to do this given that short test duration

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. The numbers were just samples but what I mainly wanted to find out is the location of the timer. I will try it out